# Can a fan in a room cool down objects?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, cooling

Does a fan cool objects?  I have a ceiling fan in my office which really helps to keeps the room cool.  Does it also cool down vitamins in a plastic bottle with a screw on top? My office can get very hot which is probably not good for them.  I keep them in my office to remember to take them. :-)  I leave the fan going to keep them cool but my husband swears it does not change the temperature for them.

Comment: Do you have objective proof that the fan in your office keeps THE ROOM cool, e.g., comparing thermometer readings with fan on and fan off and not just that it feels cooler to you? Fans work by moving air over a person thus improving evaporation of perspiration.

Answer (score 5):

A fan can keep a person cool by two methods: (1) increasing the rate of evaporation of sweat off the skin, and (2) moving air warmed by the person's body away from their skin. See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/548955/why-does-moving-air-feel-colder/548959#548959) for more details. A bottle of vitamins does not sweat nor maintain [homeostasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis), so blowing air on it does not affect its temperature.

The plastic bottle is a decent insulator, so the vitamins will stay near a temperature between the hottest room temperature (during the day) and the coldest (at night). Putting them in a drawer will further reduce the changes in temperature.